# Resetting margin-left on wrapping?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am building a horizontal navigation menu using Flexbox. Items can be aligned on the left (like *Home* and *Other item*) or the right side (like *About* and *Contact*):

[image]

I position the *About* und *Contact* items on the right end of the flexbox by putting them inside a `div` with `margin-left: auto`. This works fine as long as no wrapping is involved. With wrapping however, it looks like this:

[image]

The reason is obvious with `margin-left: auto` being still in front of the *About* item. How can I ensure that when wrapping is in place, the *About* item also starts on the left side? Any way to reset the left margin to zero when wrapping is in place?

Code can be found in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/stefan_at_wpf/b95qek8j/1/

For the archive, here's a copy of it:

The HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="mystyle.css" type="text/css" />
    </head>

    <body>
        <nav class="nav-hor">
            <a href="link1">Home</a>
            <a href="link2">Other item</a>

            <div class="right">
                <a href="link3">About</a>
                <a href="link4">Contact</a>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </body>
</html>
```

The CSS mystyle.css:

```
body {
    margin: 0px;
}

.nav-hor {
    display: flex;
    background-color: grey; 
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.nav-hor a {
    display: block;   
    padding: 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}

.nav-hor .right {
    display: flex;
    margin-left: auto;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

Comment: Note that the `<link>` tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Move the margin auto to the second link instead. You can also remove the wrapper for the two last links:

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
}

.nav-hor {
  display: flex;
  background-color: grey;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.nav-hor a:nth-child(2) {
  margin-right: auto;
}

.nav-hor a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<nav class="nav-hor">
  <a href="link1">Home</a>
  <a href="link2">Other item</a>

  <a href="link3">About</a>
  <a href="link4">Contact</a>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you use css Media Query..? add this media query end of your css file and find best value for min-width

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
 .nav-hor .right {
  margin-left: 0;
}
```

find max-width[Window width] value when wrapping is in place. 
hope you help this Thanks.